# bigdelim and text with multiple lines

Tags: tables, line-breaking, delimiters

I have a table with a common label for multiple lines. Using `bigdelim` I place brackets to give explanations. My explanation has too much text for one line, so I would like it to break over multiple lines. However, I have no idea how I could enable line breaks (preferably automatically, or manual, if there is no other way). My MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigdelim}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l p{8cm}}
    \hline
    One & \rdelim]{3}{*}[And here we have some long text, which I want to wrap over multiple lines please. Is that possible?] \\
    Two \\
    Three \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Current result:

[image: bigdelimExample]

[edit] After applying the suggestion given in the comments and changing the enclosing brackets for the text from `[` to `{`, I have the following result:

[image: bigdelimExample2]

[edit2] Thank you for your suggestions! When trying it out however, I found the following limitations which makes it impossible, to implement them as suggested (apologies if MWE was too minimal):

- There are even/odd numbers of rows which I need to group, the given solutions only work for odd amounts.
- The bracket's length grows based on the amount of text. Sometimes I only a little amount of text, which means, that the bracket does not span all necessary rows.

Any solution to fix that?

Comment: For a starter, you need to use `{}` braces, not `[]` brackets to enclose the delimited text.

Comment: Thank you, this gives me line breaks, however the result is not what I would expect (edit coming).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really know the purpose of this, but here's a solution:

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrbook}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigdelim}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l p{8cm}}
\hline
One & 
  \rdelim]{3}{*}[\parbox{8cm-\tabcolsep-\widthof{$\Bigg]$}}{
    And here we have some long text, which I want to wrap 
    over multiple lines please. Is that possible?}] \\
    Two \\
    Three \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

More simply, without `multirow`:

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrbook}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l m{8cm}}
\hline
$\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\left.\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
One \\
Two \\
Three \\
\end{tabular}\right]$ &
  And here we have some long text, which I want to wrap 
  over multiple lines please. Is that possible? \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Of course, something can be hidden in a macro.

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrbook}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\bracketedright}[1]{%
  $\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\left.\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  #1
  \end{tabular}\right]$% 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l m{8cm}}
\hline
\bracketedright{
  One \\
  Two \\
  Three 
} &
  And here we have some long text, which I want to wrap
  over multiple lines please. Is that possible? \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great solutions here, I will accept this one, as it's the most simple one, concerning flexibility and LOC.

Answer (score 2):

How about the following as an alternative (I also provide a possibility to stretch the delimiter to match the left rather than the right construction):

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l p{8cm}}
  \hline
  One & \raisebox{-\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{$\left]\parbox{\dimexpr8cm-1em}{And here we have some long text, 
    which I want to wrap over multiple lines please. Is that possible?}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace$} \\
  Two \\
  Three \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{l p{8cm}}
  \hline
  One & \raisebox{-1.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{$\left]\parbox{\dimexpr8cm-1em}{And here we have some long text, 
    which I want to wrap over multiple lines please. Is that possible?}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace$} \\
  Two \\
  Three \\
  Four \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{l p{8cm}}
  \hline
  One & \raisebox{-2\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{$\left]\parbox{\dimexpr8cm-1em}{And here we have some long text, 
    which I want to wrap over multiple lines please. Is that possible?}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace$} \\
  Two \\
  Three \\
  Four \\
  Five \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{l p{8cm}}
  \hline
  One & \raisebox{-2\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{$\left]
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\strut\\\strut\\\strut\\\strut\\\strut\end{tabular}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
    \parbox{\dimexpr8cm-1em}{And here we have some long text, 
      which I want to wrap over multiple lines please. Is that possible?}$} \\
  Two \\
  Three \\
  Four \\
  Five \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

`\raisebox{<raise>}[0pt][0pt]{<stuff>}` removes the height/depth of `<stuff>`, so placing the `\parbox` on the second row allows it to fill above/below that specific row.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I noticed some limitations, see edit2 in question. Any ideas for that?

Comment: @qqilihq: I've added a way of stretching the delimiter to match the left rather than the right construction. The idea is to set a zero-width `tabular` and insert a bunch of `\strut`s. I've also adjusted the `\raisebox` command to move the contents *down* (from `One`) to the middle of the `tabular` using a specific multiple of `\normalbaselineskip`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{8cm}{@{} >{$}l<{$}  X @{}}\hline
  \left.\begin{tabular}{@{\kern-\nulldelimiterspace} l }
    One \\ Two \\ Three
  \end{tabular}\right]  
  & 
  And here we have some long text, which I want to wrap over multiple
  lines please. Is that possible? \\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{8cm}{@{} >{$}l<{$} X @{}}\hline
  \left.\begin{tabular}{@{\kern-\nulldelimiterspace} l }
    One \\ Two \\ Three \\ Four
  \end{tabular}\right]  
  & 
  And here we have some long text, which I want to wrap over multiple
  lines please. Is that possible? \\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{8cm}{@{} >{$}l<{$}  X @{}}\hline
  \left.\begin{tabular}{@{\kern-\nulldelimiterspace} l }
    One \\ Two 
  \end{tabular}\right]  
  & 
  And here we have some long text, which I want to wrap over multiple
  lines please. Is that possible? \\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This still produces an overfull `\hbox` as `\hsize` doesn't take the width of `\left]` into consideration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I noticed some limitations, see edit2 in question. Any ideas for that?

Comment: @Werner: you want see it, it is 6pt which is the `\tabcolsep`!

Comment: @qqilihq: see edited answer